# Trying to Change The Condition of without using null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve a check for duplication and push items to array in the below code the functionality works well but instead of using a null is there any other way of doing it

```
array2.forEach((item) =>
   array1.includes(item)
 ? null
 : array1.push(item),
);
```

Comment: Sure, just replace `null` with `5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&&` to short circuit the operation

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  array2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
array2.forEach((item) => !array1.includes(item) && array1.push(item));
console.log(array1)
```

Comment: thanks it works as expected. a bit curious if any other ways are there

Comment: share the complete `array1` & `array2`

Comment: array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
array2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set

```
const set = new Set();
const brr = ["one","one"].forEach(item=> set.add(item));
Array.from(set) 
// --> ["one"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ES6 features like spread operator(...) and `Set`

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let array2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const mergedArrays = [...array1, ...array2];
array1 = [...new Set(mergedArrays)];    // make the array elements unique
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score -1):

this should works:

```
array1.push( ... array2.filter(item => !array1.includes(item) ) )
```

or you can switch **arrays** to **Set()**'s and use:

```
array2.forEach( item => array1.add(item) )
```